# How to set DataContext of a single control to code the behind

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, code-behind

How to set DataContext of a single control to code the behind?
Cannot use DataContext of the Windows as it points to something else.
For a single control I would like to set the DataContext to codebehind but cannot figure it out.
Not using MVVM.

This is not working as the RelativeSource appears to the ComboBox.

```
<ComboBox DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Chars}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Comma}" Width="40" PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High" />
```

It is a Page - not a Window

This works:

```
<ComboBox DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Page}}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Chars}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Comma, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="40" PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High" />
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: have you tried giving `ComboBox` a Name say `x:Name="cmBox"` and in the code-behind Loaded event assign `DataContext` directly `Loaded += (sender, args) => cmBox.DataContext = this;` where `this` is ofc the code-behind class that you want to set as the `ComboBox`'s `DataContext`

Comment: @Viv, how about upgrading your comment to an answer and Blam, could you mark this question as answered, so people don't waste time coming here to give you an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer :

since you aren't following MVVM, you could get away with giving your `ComboBox` a Name and assigning `DataContext` to it directly from your code-behind.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmBox" ... />
```

and in the code-behind class's ctor:

```
Loaded += (sender, args) => cmBox.DataContext = this;
```

saying ^^, there is nothing wrong with using a `RelativeSource` Binding to assign `DataContext` directly from xaml, It's what I'd prefer to do myself(but I do "try to" comply with MVVM in my apps).